# Как отследить утечку памяти

Tags: c++, visual-c++, память

Работаю под Visual Studio. Как узнать, есть ли в программе утечка памяти или нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможно обнаружение утечек памяти с помощью отладчика и отладочных функций кучи библиотеки CRT (библиотеки времени выполнения). Включаются они так:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

Важно, что инструкции `include`/`define` следуют в таком порядке.

Включение заголовочного файла `<crtdbg.h>` сопоставляет функции `malloc` и `free` с их отладочными версиями: `_malloc_dbg` и `free`. Инструкция `define` позволит сделать дамп утечки памяти более подробным (вообще говоря, она сопоставляет базовые версии функций кучи CRT соответствующим отладочным версиям).

Далее помещаем вызов `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` перед точкой выхода приложения для отображения отчета об утечке памяти перед завершением работы приложения:

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

Если точек выхода несколько, нет нужды писать вызов этой функции повсеместно. Достаточно вызвать в начале работы приложения функцию `_CrtSetDbgFlag`, что приведет к автоматическому вызову функции `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` в каждой точке выхода. Для этого надо установить значения двух битовых полей:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
```

По умолчанию `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` выводит отчет об утечке памяти в область **Отладка** окна **Вывод**.

Далее смотрите полученные данные, там четко указывается тип блока, его расположение, размер утечки и еще некоторая информация. Блоки бывают разных типов (см. справку CRT).

**Примечание:** В некоторых случаях `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` может ошибочно диагностировать утечку памяти, но я не буду здесь расписывать данные ситуации, если потребуется или Вы не разберетесь самостоятельно - пишите комментарии;)

Answer (score 4):

Используйте встроенный [профилировщик](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage) памяти.

Comment: Желательно отвечать более подробно.

Comment: По ссылке информация по профилированию **управляемой** памяти, это имеет отношение к C++ ?

Comment: @Alex Titov, C++ можно использовать как с управляемой, так и неуправляемой памятью. Профилировщик работает и там и там.